# Pass fact to role on another host

Tags: ansible

I have 2 hostgroups: A and B. The role executed on hostgroup B needs to do something with the IP address of hostgroup A. How can I make the IP address of hostgroup A available for host B?

**hosts**

```
[A]
example.host.a.com

[B]
example.host.b.com
```

**deploy.yml**

```yaml
---
- name: Gather ip address of host A
  hosts: A
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      a_host_ip: "{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address  }}"

- name: Debug result
  hosts: A
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Host A ip adress: {{ a_host_ip}}" # prints correct ip address

- name: Deploy role on host B that has to access host A ip address
  hosts: B
  gather_facts: true
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - role: role_b
```

**role_b/tasks/main.yml**

```yaml
---
# 1. try
- debug:
    msg: "IP of host A: {{ a_host_ip }}" # Error: 'a_host_ip' is undefined

# 2. try
- debug:
    msg: "IP of host A: hostvars['A'].a_host_ip" # Error: hostvars['A'] is undefined

# 3. try
- debug:
    msg: "IP of host A: hostvars['A'].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address " # Error: hostvars['A'] is undefined
```

Comment: `Nothing worked.` <= this is really far from an accurate description of how you tried exactly ans what happened when you did. Meanwhile, why don't you just get the source information? => `{{ hostvars['A'].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}`. And while we are at it: did you actually debug `{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}` in host `A` as a start to make sure it is defined, contains a value, etc.

Comment: Ok, just saw your edit with your inventory. `A` is a *group name* **not** a *hostname*. So to get your value from `hostvars` => `"{{ hostvars['example.host.a.com'].a_host_ip }}"`. As reported before, you don't need that extra `set_fact` and you can get the info from it's source location => `{{ hostvars['example.host.a.com'].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}` (provided that var exists in the given host facts)

Comment: Hi, thank you this was working! I edited my question with the required information. Can you post your solution as answer so that I can accept it?